# Python Decorator, Wrapper got argument multiple times

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I wrote this decorator to be used by two functions:

```
def next_page(func) -> List[Dict]:
    """
    Decorator to re-run api call if number of objects returned is 100.
    SmartSurvey API can only return objects for 1 "page" at each call.
    One page stores 100 objects. By passing the argument page += 1 you can get
    the next 100 records till the call return less than 100.

    :param func:
    :return: list of dictionaries
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(ASO, page, **kwargs):
        list_of_records = []
        partial_list = func(ASO, page, **kwargs)
        list_of_records.extend(partial_list)
        while len(partial_list) == 100:
            page += 1
            partial_list = func(ASO, page, **kwargs)
            list_of_records.extend(partial_list)
        return list_of_records

    return wrapper


@next_page
def _get_responses(ASO, page, survey_id, since) -> List[Dict]:
    """
    Get responses from SmartSurvey API based on survey id.
    :param ASO: API object
    :param survey_id: INTEGER
    :param page: INTEGER
    :param since: INTEGER (unix epoch)
    :return: list of dictionaries
    """
    responses = ASO.get_responses(page=page, survey_id=survey_id,
                                  since=since, page_size=100)

    return responses


@next_page
def _get_surveys(ASO, page) -> List[Dict]:
    """
    Get surveys from SmartSurvey API.
    :param ASO: API object
    :param page: INTEGER
    :return: list of dictionaries
    """
    surveys = ASO.get_surveys(page=page, page_size=100)

    return surveys
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asportelli/gitRepos/smart-survey/scripts/api_to_s3_local.py", line 206, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/asportelli/gitRepos/smart-survey/scripts/api_to_s3_local.py", line 202, in main
    responses_to_s3(s3, API, survey_meta_data, _last_n_hours(1))
  File "/Users/asportelli/gitRepos/smart-survey/scripts/api_to_s3_local.py", line 160, in responses_to_s3
    since=since)
TypeError: wrapper() got multiple values for argument 'page'
```

How can I pass the argument page recursively without having it multiple times?

Thanks!

EDIT:

functions are called as in:

```
def surveys_metadata(ASO) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    get id and last updated ts of all surveys

    :param ASO: Api Scraper Object
    :param from_ts: unix epoch timestamp
    :return: pandas df
    """
    dfs = []
    surveys = _get_surveys(ASO, page=1)
    for survey in surveys:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'id': [survey['id']],
             'date_modified': [survey['date_modified']]})
        dfs.append(df)
    output = pd.concat(dfs)
    logger.info(f"surveys_found: {len(output)}")

    return output


def responses_to_s3(s3, ASO, df, since=_last_n_hours(24 * 1)):
    """
    Write SmartSurvey responses to AWS S3 bucket.
    :param s3: boto3 client
    :param ASO: API object
    :param df: smart survey metadata (pd.DataFrame)
    :param since: INTEGER (unix epoch)

    :return:
    """
    for survey_id in df['id']:
        responses = _get_responses(ASO, survey_id, page=1,
                                   since=since)

        logger.info(f"Extracted {len(responses)} from survey: {survey_id}")
        for response in responses:
            response_id = response['id']
            response_ts = response['date_modified']
            date = str(response['date_modified'])[:10]
            _dict_to_s3(s3, 'dundata-nonprod-lake',
                        f'to_process/smart-survey/responses/{date}/'
                        f'{survey_id}-{response_id}-{response_ts}.json',
                        response)
```

Comment: How are you calling the functions `_get_surveys` and `_get_responses`?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami I made an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positional arguments in python must be passed in order of definition in the function prototype.
This line passes the value of `survey_id` to the argument `page` as it's the second argument passed.

```
responses = _get_responses(ASO, survey_id, page=1,
                                   since=since)
```

Call the function as:

```
responses = _get_responses(ASO, 1, survey_id=survey_id, 
                                   since=since)
```